# create a phone Gap app by just passing the url of website

Tags: phonegap

I have created a phone gap app  by just passing the url of my developed website into my PhoneGap project but in the app addressbar is coming want to remove that

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

```
            function onDeviceReady() {                 
                window.open('http://hitchmeright.com', '_self ', 'location=yes');
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is likely opening the url in the InAppBrowser. From the [InAppBrowser docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/):

> `_self`: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

So you need to [whitelist your url](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html).

Now that said, this is not a good design for a  PhoneGap application, and will likely provide a terrible user experience. You're treating PhoneGap as a browser rather than a hybrid app. You should build your PhoneGap app properly (package your web assets and load them locally), and only load data from the server as needed. I'd recommend doing a bit more research and checking out some example apps.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding